# How to convert nested js Object to nested HTML <li> list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, html-lists

Consider the following JS object:

```
const contObj = {
            title:"Webpage Title",
            1:{
                head:"Heading 01",
                cont:[
                    "ListItem 0101",
                    "ListItem 0102",
                    "ListItem 0103",
                    "ListItem 0104",
                    {
                        stmt: "ListItem 0105",
                        option: [
                            "SubListItem 0105-01",
                            "SubListItem 0105-02"
                        ]
                    },
                    "ListItem 0106",
                    "ListItem 0107",
                    {
                        stmt: "ListItem 0108",
                        option: [
                            "SubListItem 0108-01",
                            "SubListItem 0108-02",
                            "SubListItem 0108-03",
                            "SubListItem 0108-04",
                            "SubListItem 0108-05"
                        ]
                    },
                    "ListItem 0109",
                    "ListItem 0110"
                ]
            },
            2:{ ...
            },
            3:{ ...
            },
            4:{ ...
            }
     }
```

I want to use this object to fill up the empty webpage such that I get,

```
    <h2>Webpage Title</h2>
    <div class='top3'>
        <h3>Heading 01</h3>
        <ol type="1">
            <li>ListItem 0101</li>
            <li>ListItem 0102</li>
            <li>ListItem 0103</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <ol type='1' start='4'>
        <li>ListItem 0104</li>
        <li>ListItem 0105
            <ol type="a">
                <li>SubListItem 0105-01</li>
                <li>SubListItem 0105-02</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>ListItem 0106</li>
        <li>ListItem 0107</li>
        <li>ListItem 0108
            <ol type="a">
                <li>SubListItem 0108-01</li>
                <li>SubListItem 0108-02</li>
                <li>SubListItem 0108-03</li>
                <li>SubListItem 0108-04</li>
                <li>SubListItem 0108-05</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>ListItem 0109</li>
        <li>ListItem 0110</li>
    </ol>
    <div class='top3'>
        <h3>Heading 02</h3>
        <ol type="1">
            <li>ListItem 0201</li>
            <li>ListItem 0202
                <ol type="a">
                    <li>SubListItem 0202-01</li>
                    <li>SubListItem 0202-02</li>
                    <li>SubListItem 0202-03</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>ListItem 0203</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <ol type='1' start='4'>
        <li>ListItem 0204</li>
        ...
    </ol>
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
$(function () {
 const conObj = {
  title:"Webpage Title",
  1:{
   head:"Heading 01",
   cont:[
    "ListItem 0101",
    "ListItem 0102",
    "ListItem 0103",
    "ListItem 0104",
    {
     stmt: "ListItem 0105",
     option: [
      "SubListItem 0105-01",
      "SubListItem 0105-02"
     ]
    },
    "ListItem 0106",
    "ListItem 0107",
    {
     stmt: "ListItem 0108",
     option: [
      "SubListItem 0108-01",
      "SubListItem 0108-02",
      "SubListItem 0108-03",
      "SubListItem 0108-04",
      "SubListItem 0108-05"
     ]
    },
    "ListItem 0109",
    "ListItem 0110"
   ]
  },
  2:{
   head:"Heading 02",
   cont:[
    "ListItem 0201",
    {
     stmt: "ListItem 0202",
     option: [
      "SubListItem 0202-01",
      "SubListItem 0202-02",
      "SubListItem 0202-03"
     ]
    },
    "ListItem 0203",
    {
     stmt: "ListItem 0204",
     option: [
      "SubListItem 0204-01",
      "SubListItem 0204-02",
      "SubListItem 0204-03",
      "SubListItem 0204-04"
     ]
    },
    {
     stmt: "ListItem 0205",
     option: [
      "SubListItem 0205-01",
      "SubListItem 0205-02",
      "SubListItem 0205-03",
      "SubListItem 0205-04",
      "SubListItem 0205-05",
      "SubListItem 0205-06",
      "SubListItem 0205-07"
     ]
    },
    "ListItem 0206",
    "ListItem 0207",
    "ListItem 0208",
    "ListItem 0209",
    "ListItem 0210"
   ]
  }
 }
 $("#main").prepend("<h2>" + conObj.title + "</h2>");

 var conObjLen = Object.keys(conObj).length;
 console.log(conObjLen);
 for (const i in conObj) {
  const typ = typeof conObj[i];
  if ( typ == "object" ) {
   $("#main").append("<h3>" + conObj[i].head + "</h3> <div class='top3'><ol></ol></div> <ol type='1' start='4'></ol>");
   const contListSrt = conObj[i].cont.slice(0, 3);
   const contListEnd = conObj[i].cont.slice(3, conObj[i].cont.length);
   console.log(conObj[i].head + " >> " +contListSrt);
   console.log(conObj[i].head + " << " +contListEnd);
   for (const j in contListSrt) {
    const conttyp = typeof contListSrt[j];
    if(conttyp == "object"){
     $(".top3:last-of-type > ol").append("<li>" + contListSrt[j].stmt + "<ol type='a'></ol></li>");
     const opt = contListSrt[j].option;
     for (const l in opt) {
      if (opt.hasOwnProperty(l)) {
       $(".top3:last-of-type > ol > li > ol").append("<li>" + opt[l] + "</li>");
      }
     }
    }
    else{
     $(".top3:last-of-type > ol").append("<li>" + contListSrt[j] + "</li>");
    }
   }
   for (const k in contListEnd) {
    const conttyp = typeof contListEnd[k];
    if(conttyp == "object"){
     $(".top3:last-of-type + ol").append("<li>" + contListEnd[k].stmt + "<ol type='a'></ol></li>");
     const opt = contListEnd[k].option;
     console.log(contListEnd[k].stmt + ">>>" + opt);
     for (const m in opt) {
      $(".top3:last-of-type + ol > li > ol").append("<li>" + opt[m] + "</li>");
     }
    }
    else{
     $(".top3:last-of-type + ol").append("<li>" + contListEnd[k] + "</li>");
    }
   }
  }
 }
});
```

```css
.top3{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='main'></div>
```

The code is messy but it works. The only problem I am not able to solve is that the `SubListItems` some times get repeated or a `SubListItem` of a different `ol` is getting appended to a totally different `ol`. I just don't understand why this is happening. The console logs give the desired list but the webpage built is wrong/repeated.

Comment: You might find it easier to just create this as HTML and then set in one go, rather than using JQuery to build it.

Comment: Chances are your HTML generated is missing some closing tags thus causing the problem(s). I'd send your generated HTML through a validator so you can figure out if some tags are missing, and work your way back from there.

Comment: @KaseyChang How to get the generated HTML? All modern browsers just close the tags by assuming priority. If I copy the HTML from the browser, it'll always be valid I think... Is there a way to get HTML output/file without a browser?

Comment: Dump the output to a file. Validate that file. Or if this went to a browser, save the file from the browser.